# MYSQL selecting all records with the most recent date

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a database that stores a history of transactions, mostly comment updates.  Therefore, I accept multiple records with the same ID.

What I need to do is pull in all of the records and display the most recent of each record.

Here is an example of 2 records with the same UID.  The highlighted record is the most recent of the 2.

[image: 2 rows from database]

Here is one of the queries I attempted:

```
 SELECT 
   uid
   ,voyage
   ,MAX(comments)
   ,MAX(edituser)
   ,MAX(editdate)
 FROM 
   table
 GROUP BY
   uid
 ORDER BY
   uid
```

Here is the same UID that is returned:

[image: result from database]

If you'll notice, it is the most recent user and editdate, but it's not the most recent comment, which should be 'THIS IS A TEST COMMENT'.

I have tried several queries, but this is the closest I've gotten to returning the most recent of every record.

I tried this link:  [SQL Select record with most recent date](//stackoverflow.com/questions/21497129/sql-select-record-with-the-most-recent-date)

But I don't think I need to use any JOINS in this case, being that everything is in the same table.

How can I make this work?

Comment: In this case, i beleive you need to use a join and a subquery like the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With something like this, you are probably better off using sub-selects.

```
SELECT 
    t1.uid,
    t1.voyage,
    (SELECT comments FROM table t2 WHERE t2.uid = t1.uid AND t2.editdate = MAX(t1.editdate) LIMIT 1) as comments,
    (SELECT edituser FROM table t2 WHERE t2.uid = t1.uid AND t2.editdate = MAX(t1.editdate) LIMIT 1) as edituser,
    (SELECT editdate FROM table t2 WHERE t2.uid = t1.uid AND t2.editdate = MAX(t1.editdate) LIMIT 1) as editdate,
FROM table t1
GROUP BY t1.uid
ORDER BY t1.uid
```

Each sub-select narrows it down to the same `uid`, and then takes the one with the most recent `editdate`.

Comment: This should suffice.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If that's what your desired output be then you should use `MIN()` instead like `MIN(comments)`

Comment: Tried that, but I'm still returning the same record with the wrong comment.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @JohnBeasley, didn't see it clearly ... you should use `min()` aggregate function

Comment: Wouldn't `MIN(comments)` just grab the first comment lexicographically?  I don't think that's what OP wants

Comment: It appears MIN is what made it work.  I was thinking I was going to have to use a series of sub-queries and whatnot.  Thank you, good sirs.

Comment: MIN didn't make it work. Try width more records than two.

Comment: I'm back...MIN seemed to have worked at first.  But for some reason, it has ceased working...

Answer (score 0):

Change your order by to editdate by descending:

```
... ORDER BY editdate DESC
```